Chlorophyll and its colour change
I heard that chlorophyll compounds react with bases and acids! The most typical example is squeezing lemon into water spinach soup, which makes the color clearer! But on some websites, people say that water spinach contains a pH indicator! I still don’t understand whether the color change in water spinach soup is due to chlorophyll or a pH indicator! And if it has a pH indicator, what is it?"

Spinach contain a variety of pigments including carotenoids, chlorophylls, xanthophylls, water-soluble vitamins, etc. Several of this compounds can participate in acid-base equilibria, and change colour. You should explore this particular.

Well, if chlorophyll significantly changed color with pH, it would be an indicator. I don't think it does, though. Some effect on axial ligands is likely, and extreme pH  would definitely affect it, but it doesn't count.

If there is any change in chlorophyll with pH, it's subtle to the eye.
That said, there are many natural pH indicators, such as those below.

Since there may be more than one chemical species changing color in each of these edible indicators, there may be natural variations in the pH range and colors. They make great lab exercises for students of all ages, but are boit accurate indicators, for that reason.
My favorite is red cabbage, which goes through a complete color change from one end of the spectrum to the other, is inexpensive, and can convert a nice soup (when cooked at home, not in the lab) to a fun indicator.
